# Showing that the integral giving the total induced drag exists

Tags: fluid-dynamics, integration, drag, aerodynamics

In John Anderson's *Fundamentals of Aerodynamics* the following expression for the total induced drag is given on page 442
$$D_i = \rho_\infty V_\infty \int_{-\frac{b}{2}}^{\frac{b}{2}}\Gamma(y)\alpha_i(y)dy$$

On page 191 of *Applications of Modern Hydrodynamics to Aeronautics* Prandtl uses the small angle assumption to simplify the expression to
$$D_i = \rho_\infty \int_{-\frac{b}{2}}^{\frac{b}{2}}\Gamma(y)w(y)dy$$

The problem is that there are many reasonable circulation distributions which produce a downwash distribution that becomes unbounded at the wingtips. For example, $\Gamma\colon(-\frac{b}{2},\frac{b}{2})\to \mathbb{R}$ given by $\Gamma(x) = -x^2+1$ yields unbounded downwash at the tips. Thus it does not seem trivial to me that $\Gamma(y)w(y)$ should be integrable from $-b/2$ to $b/2$. Is $\Gamma(y)w(y)$ guaranteed to be bounded on $(-\frac{b}{2},\frac{b}{2})$ for nice enough functions? I haven't found any source showing that this should be true. The non-simplified expression for induced drag does not have this issue. We have
$$\alpha_i(x)=\textrm{tan}^{-1}\left(\frac{w(x)}{V_\infty}\right)$$

thus $\alpha_i$ is bounded since $\textrm{tan}^{-1}$ is a bounded function. Can anyone prove or disprove that the simplified integral is guaranteed to exist? If not then why does Prandtl use this simplification?

Answer (score 0):

Any valid circulation function $\Gamma$ needs to satisfy the fundamental equation of Prandtl's lifting line theory:
$$\alpha(y_0) = \frac{\Gamma(y_0)}{\pi V_\infty c(y_0)} + \alpha_{L=0}(y_0) + \frac{1}{4\pi V_\infty}\int_{-b/2}^{b/2}\frac{d\Gamma / dy}{y_0-y}dy.$$
$\Gamma(y_0)$ is considered to be a continuous function over the closed interval $\left[-\dfrac{b}{2}, \dfrac{b}{2}\right]$, and is equal to zero at the two extremes $y=\pm \dfrac{b}{2}$. Therefore, by the [extreme value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem), $\Gamma$ is bounded, and so is $\Gamma(y_0)/c(y_0)$ for any finite positive chord length $c$.

$\alpha(y_0)$ and $\alpha_{L=0}(y_0)$ are the current angle of attack and the zero-lift angle of attack respectively, and thus are also bounded between $\pm \dfrac{\pi}{2}$.

Therefore, for the equation to remain valid, the integral term
$$\int_{-b/2}^{b/2}\frac{d\Gamma / dy}{y_0-y}dy$$
needs to be finite for all $y_0$. This means that the downwash given by
$$w(y_0) = \frac{1}{4\pi}\int_{-b/2}^{b/2}\frac{d\Gamma / dy}{y_0-y}dy$$
is also finite, and $\Gamma(y_0)w(y_0)$ is bounded over $\left[-\dfrac{b}{2}, \dfrac{b}{2}\right]$.

Answer (score 0):

The physical assumption in Prandl's lifting-line theory is that a thin vortex sheet is shed from the wing's trailing edge and extends downstream far enough that the flow may be considered two dimensional.

As such, many results from 2-D potential flow directly apply. In particular, the possible singular behavior of the flow at the tip (if the flow goes around it) is the same as the flow around the leading edge of a thin airfoil, where it is known the local velocity becomes infinite (except at an ideal angle of attack) and yet the force components remain finite. This result is unchanged when small-angle assumptions are made.

This result follows most readily by noting that the force is proportional to the total circulation, but it can also be obtained by considering the local flow. The flow over a flat plate at an angle of attack goes to infinity as the inverse of the square-root of the distance from the leading edge, which is weak enough to have a finite value for its integral. Any stronger singularity (such as the example given in the question) would cause the flow to turn by greater than 180°, meaning that the flow crosses itself (a physical impossibility).